Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS Grub fails installation with: failed to register the EFI boot entry: Input/Output error
The Ubuntu installation fails on a stage where grub tries to update EFI bios.
The server is quite old and discontinued of official support, but it  has comprehensive hw for my linux dev purposes.
Platform: Intel SR1625ur
Motherboard: s5520ur
Bios: 64 rev

The installation I do:

Rufus USB GPT, FAT32 latest Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS iso file
Follow step-by-step Ubuntu installation (Language/../Network/../user-name click Continue)
The filesystem as offered default
/
/boot
/boot/efi
Installation starts. .. Installing kernel. OK.. Fils on
grub trying to install on target device

According to detailed log the errors as follows:
grub-install: warning: Cannot set EFI variable Boot0000
grub-install: warning: efivarsfs_set_variable: writing to fd 8 failed: Input/Output error
grub-install: warning: efivarsfs_set_variable:failed to unlink ...
grub-install: error: failed to register the EFI boot entry: Input/Output error

After 2 days of investigations I came up to

My motherboard firmware is buggy and it has issues working with external updates of EFI
I have to use --no-nvram OR --removable parameters during the installation process
After successful installation set manually in bios EFI target path (eg \EFI\Ubuntu\grubx64.efi)

But I don't know how to tell Ubuntu installation process to use --no-nvram OR --removable instructions.
I'm, stuck.
Please help.

My understanding is you have managed to update the nvram by hand and you wish to install the rest of grub. Is that right? Effectively re-install grub using the --no-nvram flag? That sort of looks like what you have already done with the nvram bit failing. However, to re-install it follow the instructions in the following link https://www.shellhacks.com/reinstall-grub-from-live-usb-uefi-lvm/ except when you 'install-grub' add the additional flag as follows 'update-grub --no-nvram /dev/sdX'
